# Error when importing photos with PhotoImport Plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, import, photos, geotag

I have a lot of Photos with  lat, long, and altitude information. When I start the import, I get an error message.

Do I need to prepare a blank point layer before importing? Is there another Python Plugin that is required?

I use win7 and Lisboa.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to install the software ExifTool. The most direct method is to follow the link below,

http://hub.qgis.org/projects/geotagphotos/wiki
which recommends for windows users the download from
http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

I have followed this and the Geotag Photo tool in QGIS works for me. 
I once found a problem when I had more than one install of ExifTool, but no problems now.

Comment: You will also need to configure the path to the exiftool.exe, by making the setting in the plugin's menu. You will have to edit the exiftool filename to exiftool.exe

Answer (score 1):

I came across this very old question a few times, and maybe others, too: This **Plug-in is not needed any more**, there's an easier way:

Since QGIS 3.14 **this is supportet natively** under `Processing Toolbox > Vector creation > Import geotagged photos`

The documentation of the tool can be found here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#import-geotagged-photos

A nice how-to + displaying the images as thumbnails and/or showing them on hover-over can be found here: https://opengislab.com/blog/2020/8/23/mapping-and-viewing-geotagged-photos-in-qgis

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you do have to install ExifTools manually as mentioned in the other posts above. But I could not get it working without knowing where to install it to.

1. Download the python library from [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ExifRead][1]
2. Extract the folder "ExifRead-2.1.1" (the version number may vary) to any location on your harddrive. Although "C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages" should be prefered.
3. In the folder "C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages" (or any other folder that is configured within the QGIS python-path environement) add a new file "exiftools.pth" with just one line of text containing the path to the folder where you extracted the files at step 1 into. You may need admin privileges to do so. In my case that file would contain the following line:

C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages.

4. Restart QGIS for an update of the pythonpath environement.