# photo georeferencing and python error

Tags: pyqgis, import, photos, geotag

I write because I can’t use the plugin “Geotag and Import photos”. My version is 2.18.13 Las Palmas and it runs on WIN 7 Home.
First of all, when I click on “Import photos” and specify the path to photos, I obtain the following error message:
[image]

The details are:

```
File "C:/Users/Emazza/.qgis2/python/plugins\geotagphotos\importphotosdialog.py", line 88, in selectPhotosDir
            self.loadTags(dirName)
          File "C:/Users/Emazza/.qgis2/python/plugins\geotagphotos\importphotosdialog.py", line 125, in loadTags
            with et:
          File "C:/Users/Emazza/.qgis2/python/plugins\geotagphotos\exiftool.py", line 179, in __enter__
            self.start()
          File "C:/Users/Emazza/.qgis2/python/plugins\geotagphotos\exiftool.py", line 162, in start
            stderr=devnull)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
            errread, errwrite)
          File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
            startupinfo)
        WindowsError: [Error 2] Impossibile trovare il file specificato
```

The pointer begins to rotate as if it is working; nevertheless, I can still use the software.
Even if I succeed to insert the output shapefile, I can’t see any EXIF tag.
[image]

I already installed Exiftool and I can’t understand which is the problem.
Any suggestions for these two problems?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to configure Exif as well as install it. Towards the bottom, [How to use QGIS Photo import plugin?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35128) gives some instructions on what to do for Windows